# Optimize the $$ function (prototypejs)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In an application I am working on, I use prototype's $$ function to get all the A HREF elements on a page and alter their link via javascript. This works fine as long as there is a reasonable amount of links on the page.

In some rare usecases the $$ function returns 5K+ hits (aweful :)) is there any way to optimize its behavior, or get rid of it completely for something more performant?

*edit* — important detail from the comments

The specific code is:

```
$$('a:not([href="#"])').each(function(item){});
```

I am using prototypejs 1.7.1

Comment: Well if there really are 5000 `<a>` tags on the page, what's to be done?

Comment: Also if you're using a recent version of the library, it's using a very efficient selector engine to do that work.  Are you actually noticing something being slow?  What exactly does your selector look like?

Comment: It is $$('a:not([href="#"])').each(function(item){}); ... I am using prototypejs 1.7.1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your selector is a little slow, it's probably the `:not()` that's doing it.  You can filter out those with explicit code, starting from a list of all the `<a>` elements:

```
var anchors = $$('a').reject(function(a) { return a.href === '#'; });
```

(My Prototype is pretty rusty :)  This holds true for any modern library using Sizzle. Those pseudo-selector operators like `:not` are not very efficient; they're useful as shorthand when the situation doesn't involve large scale factors, but not a great idea in a case like yours. Finding all the `<a>` elements in a document is *really* fast, and then iterating through that list should be pretty fast too.

Comment: Lol of course the fact that `:not` was being used was ninja commented silently on the question comments

Comment: @Esailija yes, sigh. I guess I anticipated that the question itself would be updated; maybe I'll do that now.

Answer (score 2):

You could go about this in a completely different manner.

take for instance you have a table with 5000 records

```
<table id="recordtable">
<tr>
    <td>Record 1</td>
    <td><a href="#link1">click here</a></td>
</tr>
......//snip
<tr>
    <td>Record 100</td>
    <td><a href="#link100">click here</a></td>
</tr>
.......//snip
</table>
```

now put an observer on the table watching for clicks on links

```
$('recordtable').on('click','a:not([href="#"])',function(e){
    //FYI 'this' points to the table element
    //e is the event object passed in-------------------^^^
    //use e.findElement() to get the element that the click originated on
    var el = e.findElement();
    if(el.readAttribute('href') != "something")
    {
        window.location.href = 'some other link';
    }
    //most importantly stop the event so that the link doesn't fire
    e.stop();
});
```

Comment: Note that his code involves Prototype, not jQuery, but yes you're right.

Comment: Wow I've forgotten more Prototype than I thought I had!  Sorry.